# MIP Java SDK error: Can't load D:\eclipse_workspace\aip-service\mip_java.dll

Tags: java, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection, mip-sdk

I am trying to use the MIP java sdk wrapper for reading and writing labels from/to a file from a java program. I have downloaded the mip sdk wrapper and copied all the DLLs to the project root folder. However, when I am trying to run the program, I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load D:\eclipse_workspace\aip-service\mip_java.dll . Error was:D:\eclipse_workspace\aip-service\mip_java.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at com.microsoft.informationprotection.internal.utils.Loader.load(Loader.java:27)
    at com.microsoft.informationprotection.internal.utils.Loader.loadNativeLibs(Loader.java:14)
    at com.microsoft.informationprotection.MIP.initialize(MIP.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.mipsdksample.Action.<init>(Action.java:68)
    at com.microsoft.mipsdksample.App.main(App.java:54)
```

I tried `Dependencies` software to figure out the dependencies of the `mip_java.dll` and I see it as below

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to get those dependencies in red in the screenshot. Can someone please help me here?

P.S:

1. Those dll files indicated in the red are not available in the mip java sdk wrapper downloaded
2. Operating System being used is Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the VC++ Runtime.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170